# Azure table storage access times

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have data stored in Table Storage. When I try to retrieve the data I do this using the partition key and row key. I have been doing some timings to retrieve data of around 8000 bytes.

I'm getting times ranging from 500-700ms and YES my host and storage are in the same data center.

Is Table Storage really so slow or am I doing something very wrong. I was expecting access times to be more like 50ms. Bear in mind that all of my tables added together probably only hold 200 rows.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question to include a code snippet showing how you're accessing table storage, as well as the VM size, since each VM size has different network bandwidth.

Comment: Is your CPU by chance spiking during the retrieves?

Answer (score 2):

Your performance numbers certainly sound very poor - and much worse than I've seen.

There are some useful reference numbers - and some good advice - on the storage team blog - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx

For your specific problem, I suggest writing some very simple test code to measure your numbers again - if you are still seeing the same problems, then post the code here and - if your code really is trivial - then contact MS support.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to retrieve multiple entities at once? If so, there is a known bug in the query parser of the Table Storage, and **indexes does not get used when multiple entities are queried directly from their `RowKey`**, instead the request generate a linear scan of the table which can indeed take 500 to 700ms for each roundtrip.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? It could impact me greatly, so I would like some additional details. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you will find the code as part of Lokad.Cloud.Storage project. You only need to investigate https://github.com/Lokad/lokad-cloud-storage/blob/master/Source/Lokad.Cloud.Storage/Azure/TableStorageProvider.cs Hope it helps.